# R - cbind list summary elements

Tags: r, list, cluster-analysis, cbind

I wonder how I can `cbind` elements of a `summary` of a `list`.

Imagine I am running a clustering on 3 groups separately.

I am using for this purpose the `ruspini` data from the `cluster` library.

```
library(dplyr)
library(cluster)

# Let us create 3 groups 
ruspini$group = rep(1:3, 25)
```

I am first applying a `PAM` clustering. Then, I apply a `silhouette` function and finally a `summary` to each lists.

```
fpam = function(x) pam(x, 3)
fsil = function(x) silhouette(x)

ruspiniPAMsil = ruspini %>% 
    split(.$group) %>% 
    lapply(fpam) %>% 
    lapply(fsil) %>% 
    lapply(summary)
```

What I would like is to retreive this

```
ruspiniPAMsil[[1]]$clus.avg.widths
```

from each clusters and bind it together.

How do I `cbind` elements of such a list ?

```
do.call('cbind', ruspiniPAMsil[[i]]) # ??
```

The **output** wanted is

```
    Group 1   Group 2   Group 3
1 0.6944263 0.6898372 0.5436701
2 0.5286338 0.5129770 0.7421103
3 0.8200596 0.7810391 0.6460008
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to subset each element if they share the same component.

```
sapply(ruspiniPAMsil, `[[`, 'clus.avg.widths')
          1         2         3
1 0.6944263 0.6898372 0.5436701
2 0.5286338 0.5129770 0.7421103
3 0.8200596 0.7810391 0.6460008
```

Comment: Thanks that what I was looking for.